# @Sql in Spring integration test is suspending transaction for AFTER_TEST_METHOD

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions, spring-test

I have the following situation:

```
  @Test
  @Sql(scripts = "before.sql" , executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED))
  @Sql(scripts = "cleanUp.sql", executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD , config = @SqlConfig(transactionMode = ISOLATED))
```

I need the test data to be committed before the test begin(it is obligatory to be committed), and after that to clean up that data.

The problem is, when AFTER_TEST_METHOD is executed it is suspending the current transaction in order to make a new one (because of ISOLATED), so if my  mockMvc.perform(...) is locking the test data the test cannot finish because the isolated transaction is waiting for lock.

If I use INFERRED, the clean up is reusing the existing transaction which is roll-baked from the Spring transaction manager, so the committed data from BEFORE_TEST_METHOD stays.

Is there a some way to resolve this, some configuration that I'm missing ?

Thanks.

P.S I'm using testNG